# Two Container Pod Creation

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Create a Pod called sega with two containers:

Container 1: Name tails with image busybox and command: sleep 3600.
Container 2: Name sonic with image nginx and Environment variable: NGINX_PORT with the value 8080.

Just I want the yml for this one

Answer (score 2):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sega
spec:
  containers:
  - name: tails
    image: busybox
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]
  - name: sonic
    image: nginx
    env:
    - name: NGINX_PORT
      value: "8080"
```

To set environment variables in container follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container)

[This](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container) is also a good read for multi-container pod.